# How to connect to local database from local server in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, gcdwebserver

I have following scenario

1. I have Sqlite file of 4GB of data to support offline.
2. Can I copy to the app and distribute the app, does it affect
   application performance.
3. I need to read data from the same sqlite file, can I use the native
   sqlite commands to read from 4GB of sqlite file or can I run a
   server like `GCDWebServer` to read data from sqlite file. Which
   approach gives better performance.

Comment: i used itunes sharing functionality for accessing database from outside the app resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used iTunes sharing functionality for accessing database from outside the app resources, with GCDWebServer to support offline tile rendering functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ios applications that access a local Sqlite database.  I personally prefer to use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) as a library to access Sqlite.  Since Sqlite is a C library, you can call the library directly from Swift or Objective-C.  You should be able to find many tutorials on building Sqlite applications.